# How can I preview my web page on mobile platforms via the inspect element in Google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, html, preview, inspect

I'm trying to develop a website that is mobile compatible and I want to see a preview of how my pages would look like on the phone. 
I'm using Google chrome to preview my pages, is there a way to preview the mobile version in Chrome's inspect element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way:
in the devTool (inspect element in Chrome) go to drawer then the tab emulation then choose the device you want and click on emulate.